# API for combining PDF's?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I have a web app that takes pdf's from users. I need to append another pdf to the pdf uploaded by the user.  I have been unable to figure out how to do this.  Not sure if there is an external api that would let me combine/merge two pdf's.

This is an angular application with a node backend.  The file is uploaded and stored in Dropbox using FilePicker.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf# I know it generates PDFs since I've used it before, however, not sure about merging existing

Comment: Is it running on Linux or windows?

Comment: Is it required to be javascript, or can you exec another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is running on linux you can use pdfunite, chances are good that it already is installed on your system. All you need is below code, you can specify as many infiles as you like.

```
var process = require('child_process');
var deploySh = process.exec('pdfunite in-1.pdf in-2.pdf in-n out.pdf',function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael!  pdfunite is perfect and there are a few npm modules that are wrappers for it.  Ang if I host on Heroku, there's a heroku package called hypdf, which lets you utilize pdfunite in several languages - including node.  Great help!

Comment: Perfect, nice it's working! You're welcome!